# ListView Display only one Item?

Tags: android, json, listview

I am using ListView to Populate JSON Data .I Want to Display all the respective Value but only one JSON Data is setted in the ListView.Why all the Value are not Setted as the ListItem.

**test_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2E353D"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Class Schedule"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sunday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#008b8b"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:text="SUNDAY"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sunday_class"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#A4ACB0"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Subject"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Teacher"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Time"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_class_schedule"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#C5CED1" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentClassTest**

```
public class FragmentClassTest extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    LinearLayout sunday, sundaySchedule, monday, mondayClass, tuesday, tuesdayClass, wednesday, wednesdayClass, thrusday, thrusdayClass, friday, fridayClass;

    public static final String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/employeeApi/timeTableByClass";
    String master_id;

    String day;


    ListView listViewStudentClass;


    String access_token;
    String TeacherName, SubjectName, Time;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        sunday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sunday);
        monday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.monday);
        tuesday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tuesday);
        wednesday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
        thrusday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.thrusday);
        friday = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.friday);


        sundaySchedule = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sunday_class);
        mondayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.monday_class);
        tuesdayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_class);
        wednesdayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_class);
        thrusdayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.thrusday_class);
        fridayClass = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.friday_class);


        listViewStudentClass = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_class_schedule);


        sundaySchedule.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mondayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tuesdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        wednesdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        thrusdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fridayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        sunday.setOnClickListener(this);
        monday.setOnClickListener(this);
        tuesday.setOnClickListener(this);
        wednesday.setOnClickListener(this);
        thrusday.setOnClickListener(this);
        friday.setOnClickListener(this);


        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        master_id = session.getMasterId();
        access_token = session.getAccesstToken();


        makeJsonObjectRequest();
        return view;
    }

    ClassScheduleStudent classScheduleStudent;


    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?Sid=" + master_id;
        System.out.println(URL);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule = new ArrayList<>();
                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);


                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {


                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                day = jsonObject.getString("DayOfTheWeek");


                                if (day.equals("1")) {
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                    JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                    SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                    TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                    Time = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");

                                    // Log.d("ListData", "@@@ TeacherName:" + TeacherName);
                                    student_list_class_schedule.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, Time));
                                }

                            }

                            //  Log.d("ListData", "@@@ student_list_class_schedule size :" + student_list_class_schedule.size());
                            ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatpter = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule);
                            listViewStudentClass.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatpter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
/*
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", master_id);
                map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            } */
        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sunday:
                if (sundaySchedule.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    sundaySchedule.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (sundaySchedule.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    sundaySchedule.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.monday:
                if (mondayClass.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    mondayClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (mondayClass.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    mondayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.tuesday:
                if (tuesdayClass.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    tuesdayClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (tuesdayClass.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    tuesdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.wednesday:
                if (wednesdayClass.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    wednesdayClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (wednesdayClass.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    wednesdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.thrusday:
                if (thrusdayClass.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    thrusdayClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (thrusdayClass.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    thrusdayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.friday:
                if (fridayClass.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    fridayClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (fridayClass.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    fridayClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    }
```

}

**ClassScheduleStudentAdapter**

```
public class ClassScheduleStudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    Context mContext;

    ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_class_schedule=null;
    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";

    public ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_class_schedule) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.student_class_schedule = student_class_schedule;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println(student_class_schedule.size());
        return student_class_schedule.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return student_class_schedule.get(position);
        // return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // final ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder viewHolder;
        final Holder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_schedule_listitem_student, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
          //  viewHolder = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder();
            viewHolder=new Holder();

            viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Subject = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_subject);
            viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_TeacherName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_teacherName);
            viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_Time);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
          //  viewHolder = (ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"@@ postion:"+postion+" getTeacherName"+student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTeacherName());
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Subject.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getSubject());
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_TeacherName.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTeacherName());
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Time.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTime());


       // convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {


        TextView student_profile_class_schedule_Subject;
        TextView student_profile_class_schedule_TeacherName;
        TextView student_profile_class_schedule_Time;


    }




}
```

Whats the exact issue? i am not able to solve from couple of days.

> **Note Updated solution** In previously i have ListView inside ScrollVIew Which is the main reason to show only one Item .So never
>   include listView inside ScrollView since,listView is autoscrollable no
>   scrollView is needed

Comment: Do i have to do match_parent.match_parent doesnot solve the issue .

Comment: Try height of parent layout in class_schedule_listitem_student to be wrap_content and not match_parent

Comment: sorry @NIkhilGupta i didnt get you

Comment: In your class_schedule_listitem_student file.. for the first LinearLayout you have used, try giving its height as wrap_content instead of giving match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `convertView.setTag(viewHolder);` inside if `(convertView == null)`

Check log for postion value

```
@Override
public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_schedule_listitem_student, parent, false);

        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new Holder();
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Subject = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_subject);
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_TeacherName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_teacherName);
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_Time);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);//add set tag here

    } else {
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Log.d(TAG,"@@ postion:"+postion+" getTeacherName"+student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTeacherName());

    viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Subject.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getSubject());
    viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_TeacherName.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTeacherName());
    viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Time.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTime());

    return convertView;
}
```

makeJsonObjectRequest:

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    String URL = Navigation_URL + "?Sid=" + master_id;
    System.out.println(URL);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule = new ArrayList<>();
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            day = jsonObject.getString("DayOfTheWeek");
                            if(day.equals("1"))
                            {
                                JSONObject studentDetails_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teachers");
                                JSONObject studentDetails_course = jsonObject.getJSONObject("courses");
                                SubjectName = (String) studentDetails_course.get("CourseName");
                                TeacherName = studentDetails_obj.getString("NAME");
                                Time = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");

                                Log.d("ListData", "@@@ TeacherName:"+TeacherName);
                                student_list_class_schedule.add(new ClassScheduleStudent(SubjectName, TeacherName, Time));
                            }


                        }
                        Log.d("ListData", "@@@ student_list_class_schedule size :"+student_list_class_schedule.size());
                        ClassScheduleStudentAdapter classScheduleStudentAdatpter = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_class_schedule);
                        listViewStudentClass.setAdapter(classScheduleStudentAdatpter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }
        /*
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("id", master_id);
            map.put("accessID", accessID);
            map.put("currentUser", master_id);
            return map;

        } */
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Adapter Layout:

```
<TextView id="@+id/tv_Days">//For days sunday, monday ...
<RelativeLayout id="@+id/Layout1">//for lable subject,teacher...
<RelativeLayout id="@+id/Layout2">//for display all lable values
```

Model Class:

```
private day, subject,teacher;
```

In getview Adapter

```
private String previous_day="";
if(previous_day.equals("") || previous_day!=student_class_schedule.get(postion).getDay())
{

    tv_Days.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    Layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
else
{
    tv_Days.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    Layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}

.
.
//set other values
```

Comment: Add your logcat

Comment: replace above given getView method as it is.Only use final Holder viewHolder; not final ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder viewHolder;

Comment: check size of list in get count   @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println(student_class_schedule.size);
        return student_class_schedule.size();

    }


And send your logcat again

Comment: Replace your makeJsonObjectRequest with above give code and check logs

Comment: added logcat.please check.i am going to update whole code.only one name is displayed in the Layout

Comment: No issue in adapter but every time zero position is printed .. try to clean your project and rebuild

Comment: only one name is printed i.e of position[0].Cleaning and rebuilding cannot solve issue

Comment: in adapter print size of student_class_schedule..System.out.println(student_class_schedule.size); return student_class_schedule.size(); }

Comment: @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println(student_class_schedule);
        return student_class_schedule.size();

    }

Comment: print  System.out.println(student_class_schedule.size())

Comment: Size is printed as 2.
03-28 12:35:56.569 8931-8931/com.example.user.mis D/HomeTab_adapter: @@ postion:0 getTeacherNameDoris Marquez
03-28 12:35:56.571 8931-8931/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 2
03-28 12:35:56.571 8931-8931/com.example.user.mis D/HomeTab_adapter: @@ postion:0 getTeacherNameDoris Marquez
03-28 12:35:56.867 8931-8931/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 2
03-28 12:35:56.867 8931-8931/com.example.user.mis D/HomeTab_adapter: @@ postion:0 getTeacherNameDoris Marquez
03-28 12:35:56.868 8931-8931/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 2

Comment: set listview  height match_parent.. android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: not any change.
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025878/arraylist-display-only-one-value-from-a-loop-to-the-listview.lets chat

Comment: post your screenshort

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: In screen short display multiple recrods

Comment: sorry i didnot understand

Comment: In your screenshot display multiple teacher names ... then where is display only one record?

Comment: I have parsed value in Sunday only .Other are static for now only

Comment: post your whole test_layout xml

Comment: i have changed as you changed.same result

Comment: hey man .the 2nd value is shown.But i have to use scrollView to Display other Data.

Comment: ohhh great.. where is the issue ? But list view already have scroll no need  for other scrollView .At time only one scrollView  is work , either listview scroll or scrollView

Comment: issue on the Layout.as you suggest layout.2nd value is displayed.But i have to use scrollview to display other data i.e for monday+..... .how can this be possible

Comment: you get whole data from web service right? then try custom list for this view

Comment: I will surely check.Thanks alot mate

Answer (score 0):

Move this line before calling `makeJsonObjectRequest()`

```
ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule = new ArrayList<>();
    ClassScheduleStudentAdapter customFeeListStudentAdapter = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_student_fee);
                                    listViewStudentClass.setAdapter(customFeeListStudentAdapter);
```

remove  `ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_list_class_schedule = new ArrayList<>();` this line from response.
and when you get complete array list outside for loop, then call

```
classScheduleStudentAdatpter.setList(student_list_class_schedule)
classScheduleStudentAdatpter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Inside adapter,

```
private void setList( ArrayList<ClassScheduleStudent> student_class_schedule){
this.student_class_schedule = student_class_schedule;
}
```

Comment: I have done that @rohit but the issue is not solved.check edit

Comment: Can you print size of arraylist in adapter in getCount method?

Comment: the size of array got incremented .but it is not Displayed in VIew

Comment: @Suman try scrolling down the listview, do you see the remaining content there?? your item's layout height should be wrap_content. Please consider using RecyclerView

Comment: @RakeebRajbhandari i have debug ,the value is on the Arraylist but its not Displayed in the View.

Comment: All I can suspect is your arraylist size. If you are changing arraylist size after setting adapter, you should use notifyDataSetChanged() for adapter, and update arraylist in adapter by writing setter method and set it through fragment.

Comment: Can you please provide some Code Snippet

Comment: @Rohit please check updated code.The value are printed in log but why the listItem are not added in display.can you please provide some hint

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is because you have implemented wrong **view holder pattern**.

How you have implemented

```
if(convertview == null){
 ....
 ....
}else{
 viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
```

but It should be like

```
if(convertview == null){
 ....
 ....
 convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}else{
 viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}
```

so now replace **getView** method of Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_schedule_listitem_student, parent, false);

        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder();
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Subject = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_subject);
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_TeacherName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_teacherName);
        viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_Time);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
         viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Subject.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getSubject());
    viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_TeacherName.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTeacherName());
    viewHolder.student_profile_class_schedule_Time.setText(student_class_schedule.get(postion).getTime());


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: have you checked my solution?

Comment: I am not getting exactly what is issue.